# sqlalchemy session not getting removed properly in flask testing

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm using [Flask-Testing](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Testing/) which says:

> Another gotcha is that Flask-SQLAlchemy also removes the session
>   instance at the end of every request (as should any threadsafe
>   application using SQLAlchemy with scoped_session). Therefore the
>   session is cleared along with any objects added to it every time you
>   call client.get() or another client method.

However, I'm not seeing that. This test fails:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask.ext.testing import TestCase

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:////tmp/test.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
@app.route('/')
def index():
  print 'before request:', `db.session`
  u = db.session.query(User).first()
  u.name = 'bob'
  return ''

class User(db.Model):
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  name = db.Column(db.String)

class SessionTest(TestCase):

  def create_app(self):
    return app

  def test_remove(self):
    db.drop_all()
    db.create_all()

    u = User()
    u.name = 'joe'
    db.session.add(u)
    db.session.commit()
    client = app.test_client()
    client.get('/')
    print 'after request:', `db.session`
    print u.name
    assert u not in db.session
```

(Run with `$ nosetests test_file.py` to see it in action.)

stdout:

```
-------------------- >> begin captured stdout << ---------------------
before request: <sqlalchemy.orm.scoping.ScopedSession object at 0x10224c610>
after request: <sqlalchemy.orm.scoping.ScopedSession object at 0x10224c610>
bob

--------------------- >> end captured stdout << ----------------------
```

According to the docs, user `u` should not be in the session after a get request, but it is! Does anybody know why this is happening?

Furthermore, `u.name` is `bob` and not `joe`, even though the request never committed! (So I'm convinced it's the same session.)

For the record,

```
$ pip freeze | grep Flask
Flask==0.10.1
Flask-Bcrypt==0.5.2
Flask-DebugToolbar==0.8.0
Flask-Failsafe==0.1
Flask-SQLAlchemy==0.16
Flask-Script==0.6.2
Flask-Testing==0.4
Flask-Uploads==0.1.3
Flask-WTF==0.8
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the confusion comes from the fact that sessions in SQLAlchemy are *scoped*, meaning that each request handler creates and destroys its own session.

This is necessary because web servers can be multi-threaded, so multiple requests might be served at the same time, each working with a different database session.

For this reason, the session that you used outside of the context of a request is likely not the same session that the view function that handles the `'/'` route gets and then destroys at the end.

**UPDATE**: I dug around a bit and figured this thing out.

Flask-SQLAlchemy installs a hook on `app.teardown_appcontext`, and here is where it calls `db.session.remove()`.

The testing environment does not fully replicate the environment of a real request because it does not push/pop the application context. Because of that the session is never removed at the end of the request.

As a side note, keep in mind that functions registered with `before_request` and `after_request` are also not called when you call `client.get()`.

You can force an application context push and pop with a small change to your test:

```
def test_remove(self):
  db.drop_all()
  db.create_all()

  u = User()
  u.name = 'joe'
  db.session.add(u)
  db.session.commit()
  with app.app_context():
      client = app.test_client()
      client.get('/')
  print 'after request:', `db.session`
  print u.name
  assert u not in db.session
```

with this change the test passes.

The documentation for Flask-Testing seems to be wrong or more likely outdated. Maybe things worked like they describe at some point, but that isn't accurate for current Flask and Flask-SQLAlchemy versions.

I hope this helps!

Comment: That was my first guess, but the session is the same in both:

during request: <sqlalchemy.orm.scoping.ScopedSession object at 0x1062855d0>
after request: <sqlalchemy.orm.scoping.ScopedSession object at 0x1062855d0>

Comment: Sorry I misread your answer - what I am expecting IS the scoping behavior, and the problem here is that it ISN'T scoped like I expected. `u` should not be in `db.session` after the request, but it actually is.

Comment: Interesting - I was aware of the extra app_context, but I assumed a client request would push on its own. Thanks for the help; I've created an issue at https://github.com/jarus/flask-testing/issues/32

Comment: I told about it in my answer

Comment: Anyone coming here from the future, I made some interesting discoveries about Flask's request- and app-context handling here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23478870/388033

Answer (score 0):

`FlaskClient` works with request context while *Flask-SQLAlchemy* calls it's `shutdown_session` on `app.teardown_appcontext` since *Flask* version 0.9. Thats why nothing happens after test client call, bacause app context started by `flask.ext.testing.TestCase` even before test's `setUp` and will be closed after `tearDown`.

Comment: Hm, are the Flask-Testing docs just wrong, then? It's hard to believe this is expected behavior, since test requests will see each others' uncommitted changes.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem when tried to use Flask-Manage to run my tests. Running tests in a separate thread solved the problem.

```
import threading
# some code omited
runner = unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2)
t = threading.Thread(target=runner.run, args=[test_suite])
t.start()
t.join()
# other code omited
```